# How do I compare strings held in an object which are held in an ArrayList and then add the value of those strings(if they are equal to one another)

Tags: java, string, object, arraylist

How do I compare strings held in an object which are held in an ArrayList and then add the value of those strings(if they are equal to one another)?

I understand how to check if `StringX == StringY` or `StringX.equals(StringY)`, but I fail to understand to compare strings in an `ArrayList`, much less how to add the value of doubles held in the String's object(only if that string is equal).

**Example**
class BaseBallTeam has two attributes;

- String teamMember e.g. Kat
- Double homeRuns e.g. 2.0

I want to add up all the homeRuns(double) made by all the Kats(string). As well as all the homeRuns(double) made by all the mikes etc.

Heres my code:

```
ArrayList<BaseBallTeam> list = new ArrayList<>();
double totalRuns = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<list.size();i++){
   for(int j = 1; j<list.size();j++){        
    if(list.get(i).getTeamMember().equals(list.get(j).getTeamMember())){
       totalRuns += list.get(j).getHomeRuns() +list.get(i).getHomeRuns();
       System.out.println("Amount of " + list.get(i).getTeamMember() + "s hit " + totalRuns"home runs);
   }
}
```

My code provides all the team members cumulative frequency rather then adding up the two individual scores

Comment: What are you having a problem with? Your code seems to do what you say you don't understand how to do.

Comment: Show the contents of your `ArrayList`.

Comment: I need the data, like the strings and doubles stored in that ArrayList.

Comment: its all batch code i.e BaseBallTeam(Kate,2) BaseBallTeam(Kate,2)  BaseBallTeam(Mike,4)  BaseBallTeam(Mike,2)

Comment: What is your expected output for BaseBallTeam(Kate,2) BaseBallTeam(Kate,2) BaseBallTeam(Mike,4) BaseBallTeam(Mike,2) ?
Amount of Mikes hit 6 home runs
Amount of Kates hit 4 home runs 
?

Comment: @DmitriiCheremisin Yep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do your question is by using java 8 functionality. You can group all your BaseBallTeam objects by their names and sum total amount of homeRuns of each player with Collectors from java.util.stream.Collectors:

Sample code:

```
    BaseBallTeam kate1 = new BaseBallTeam("Kate", 2);
    BaseBallTeam kate2 = new BaseBallTeam("Kate", 2);
    BaseBallTeam mike1 = new BaseBallTeam("Mike", 4);
    BaseBallTeam mike2 = new BaseBallTeam("Mike", 2);

    List<BaseBallTeam> list = Arrays.asList(kate1, kate2, mike1, mike2);
    Map<String, Integer> map = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> t.getTeamMember(), 
                                      k -> k.getHomeRuns(), 
                                      (t1, t2) -> t1 + t2)
                    );
    System.out.println(map);
```

> Output: {Mike=6, Kate=4}

Here:

1. Collectors.toMap says that you want to collect all teams to HashMap
2. t -> t.getTeamMember() says to collect by their teamMember(name). teamMember becomes key of the HashMap
3. k -> k.getHomeRuns() says to collect their homeRuns as values
4. (t1, t2) -> t1 + t2 says that we want to sum values if we find duplicate keys

Then you may iterate through your map as:

```
map.entrySet().forEach(e -> 
               System.out.println("Amount of " + e.getKey() + "s hit " + e.getValue() + " home runs"));
```

Outputs:

> Amount of Mikes hit 6 home runs
>
> Amount of Kates hit 4 home runs

Answer (score 0):

You should first look what teammembers there are and then you should count their homeruns:

```
    ArrayList<BaseBallTeam> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // fill the list
    ArrayList<String> teamMembers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (!teamMembers.contains(list.get(i).getTeamMember())) {
            teamMembers.add(list.get(i).getTeamMember());
        }
    }

    double totalRuns = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < teamMembers.size(); i++) {
        double runs = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
            if (list.get(j).getTeamMember().equals(teamMembers.get(i))) {
                runs += list.get(j).getHomeRuns();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Amount of " + teamMembers.get(i) + "s hit " + runs + " home runs");
        totalRuns += runs;
    }
    System.out.println("Total homeruns " + totalRuns);
```

Comment: For some reason I'm getting; Amount of Kates hit 4 home runs twice

Comment: What ist your input in the list?

Comment: I got two kates both with 2 runs between them: (String Kate, double 2) and (String Kate, double 2). When i print the code this happens: Kates hit 4 home runs **next line** Kates hit 4 home runs. I only want Kate to be displayed once

Comment: Your two Kate must be written identical. No spaces, no different upper or lower case letters. kate and Kate are different. Since I cannot see how you set the input I can say here nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer works well. Here is an idea to simplify the code and improve readability (it does the same thing though!):

```
BaseBallTeam kate1 = new BaseBallTeam("Kate", 2.0);
BaseBallTeam kate2 = new BaseBallTeam("Kate", 3.0);
BaseBallTeam mike1 = new BaseBallTeam("Mike", 1.0);
BaseBallTeam mike2 = new BaseBallTeam("Mike", 5.0);
List<BaseBallTeam> list = Arrays.asList(kate1, kate2, mike1, mike2);

ArrayList<String> teamMembers = new ArrayList<>();
for(BaseBallTeam team : list){
  if(!teamMembers.contains(team.getTeamMember())){
    teamMembers.add(team.getTeamMember());
  }
}

double totalRuns = 0;

for(String teamMember : teamMembers){
  double runs = 0;
  for(BaseBallTeam team : list){
    if(team.getTeamMember().equals(teamMember)){
      runs += team.getHomeRuns();
    }
  }
  System.out.println("Amount of " + teamMember + "s hit " + runs + " home runs");
  totalRuns += runs;
}
System.out.println("Total homeruns " + totalRuns);
```

Comment: The code prints out the same string twice rather than once

Comment: That should not happen, when all the names are spelled identically. I will edit my answer and fill in the `fill the list` part.

Comment: I get this output:  `Amount of Kates hit 5.0 home runs
Amount of Mikes hit 6.0 home runs
Total homeruns 11.0`